# JSON editing problem while trying to access in a @event, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await

Sorry if I do this code part wrong, but I think I am learning how to do so. Anyways, my problem is that I am trying to access users.json (has worked in the past) to fetch users coins, however I need to do this per @event I assume because I need to be able to access the variable I set the json.load() equal too. Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/main/paeth.py", line 283, in on_reaction_add
    users = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
```

If you are looking for the code this is making this happen, here is the @client.event for on_reaction_add

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)  

    global QUEUE

    print(str(reaction.emoji))
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:csgo:544232345620709376>":
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="CS:GO")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("Added role CS:GO to user: " + str(user))
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:overwatch:544232310896328739>":
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Overwatch")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("Added role Overwatch to user: " + str(user))
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:apex:544232279325540359>":
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Apex Legends")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("Added role Apex Legends to user: " + str(user))
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:cod:544232280374247453>":
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Call of Duty")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("Added role Call of Duty to user: " + str(user))
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "<:fortnite:544232365313228800>":
        role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="Fortnite")
        await client.add_roles(user, role)
        print("Added role Fortnite to user: " + str(user))
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
        print("User " + str(user) + " has just joined the queue.")
        QUEUE.append(str(user))
        if str(QUEUE[0]) == "PaethBot#1265":
            QUEUE.remove(QUEUE[0])
        else:
            await client.send_message(user, "You have been added to the queue!")
            print(QUEUE)
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "":
        print("User " + str(user) + " has just attempted to join the bank heist")
        if str(user) == "PaethBot#1265":
            print("Removing Bot's Eligibility")
        else:
            tempCoins = users[user]['coins']
            if tempCoins < joinIn:
                await client.send_message(user, "Sorry, but your heist-mates saw that you didn't have enough coins to join them, and kicked you to the curb!")
            else:
                await client.send_message(user, "Congrats! Your heist-mates accepted your join request and took your " + str(joinIn) + " coins!")
                await client.send_message(user, "Check in on the bankheist channel to see progress")
                users[user]['coins'] -= int(joinIn)
                HEIST.append(str(user))

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Here is my users.json file: Just checked, apparently it is empty? Let me try to fix.

Whole users.json:

```
{"265749200468180992": {"coins": 10}, "543968234685071370": {"coins": 0}}
```

New problem is that it keeps getting wiped, here is my code:

[Can't add it because it is too long, and I know you guys don't like hastebin's]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you include your JSON (or just a sample if it's quite large)? From the error it looks like there's an error in it.

Comment: @Harry Cuts of course! I’ll edit it now!

Comment: Hey @HarryCutts turns out that it is now empty? it was working before, any ideas as to why or how to fix?

Comment: It can't be loaded, because it's empty. Something deleted or overwrote (with nothing) the content.

Comment: In addition you should use `open('users.json', 'wt')` with the mode `wt` to save you changes.

Comment: A common mistake here is which directory you're running the Python script in. If you're running it in a different directory to the one that contains `users.json`, you'll have to specify the full path.

Comment: @HarryCutts Thanks for the response, I have it in the same directory, so I don't think thats the issue

Comment: @DariusMorawiec Hey thanks for the response! I have gone ahead and changed it to 'wt', however I don't know how it is supposed to be formatted? Any help, if not I will be looking into youtube videos while I await your response.